# Having problems implemeting Regex into Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell

So I have an assignment due and it's asking to utilize RegEx with Haskell to come up with a solution. I will link it at the bottom. Basically, my issues does not lie within the Regex, I understand how to find 2As using Regex normally, but when it comes to Haskell and this declaration, I don't know how to actually go about this without finding an error.

I've tried my own implementations of the RegEx: which is [AA]{2} in the case of just finding 2 As, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it work in Haskell, and the declaration given was much more confusing.

```
module Project3 where

data RE a
    = Symbol a
    | Empty
    | RE a :+: RE a
    | RE a :|: RE a
    | Repeat (RE a)
    | Plus (RE a)
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

data ABC = A | B | C deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)


atMost2As :: RE ABC
atMost2As = undefined
```

This is the current problem. I have been trying to mess around with '=~ "[AA]{2}"', and similar concepts, but I still am getting errors since this does not expect arguments.

The language for atMost2As includes exactly those strings in which A occurs no more than twice, is what it is supposed to yield. Overall I can't find the issue.

Comment: Exactly which regex library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Text.Regex.PCRE library for this. If that's not what you were asking for sorry, I'm still new to haskell.

Comment: Thanks @PrakharNair, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Haskell has lots of regex libraries and they all behave slightly differently.

Comment: Also @PrakharNair, could you edit your question to format your code properly? You can do it by highlighting your code block and pressing `Control+K`.

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed it.

Comment: A few questions on your code now: what is `RE` for? How is it related to the `regex-pcre` library you're using? As far as I can see `atMost2As` should be `(Symbol A :+: Symbol A) :|: (Symbol A :|: Empty)` - is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Oh, okay I see. Yeah RE was the structure provided, but since I was having issues with that I wanted to see if I could use `regex-pcre`. What you see makes a lot more sense, thank you very much for the assistance, it'll help me finish the rest of the assignment.

Comment: You're welcome @PrakhairNair. Should I put my solution as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I think that made a lot of sense, and I'm honestly surprised I didn't think about it like that!

Comment: Voting to close for exactly the same reason I voted to close [this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619622/i-need-help-understanding-how-to-do-the-function-in-haskell-atmost2as) last week.

Answer (score 1):

```
atMost2As :: RE ABC
atMost2As = undefined
```

As I mentioned in the comments, a reasonable implementation for this could be:

```
atMost2As = (a :+: a) :|: (a :|: Empty)
  where
    a = Symbol A
```

This describes a regex where there are at most two `a`s: either there are two `a`s, or there is one `a`, or the solution is `Empty`.